# preg_quote and escaping single quotes

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match Artist Names in Event Titles using a regular expression. My Artist Names can contain a wide variety of characters. I am using preg_quote() to escape special characters for my regular expression.

When my string doesn't contain any quotes, this is fine. But, when it does, I encounter problems.

For the following string:

`80's VS 90's Party Featuring Stifler's Mom (the Ultimate 90's Experien`

a combination of

`addslashes(preg_quote($str))`

...produces the following error:

`Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 94`

If I remove addslashes(), then my regular expression fails later on the following subject string:

`Kruger Gallery's Garza Marfa Furniture & Textile Design Opening Reception`

...producing the following error:

`Message: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'G'`

How can I compose a regular expression that will tolerate the presence of any special characters, in combination with single and/or double quotes?

At present, my regular expressions are compiled a loop, for each artist I test, with this:

```
$pattern = "'`\b" . addslashes(preg_quote($artist_name, '`')) . "\b`'";
```

I'm using the back tick as a delimiter because they appear to be the least likely character to be encountered in my artist names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be building your regex like this:

```
$re = '`' . preg_quote($input, '`') . '`';
```

Remove `\b` as your input may start with a non-word character as well.

**Testing:**

```
$input="*Testing:* 80's VS 90's Party Featuring Stifler's Mom (the Ultimate 90's Experien";
preg_match($re, $input, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => *Testing:* 80's VS 90's Party Featuring Stifler's Mom (the Ultimate 90's Experien
)
```

Comment: Ok - I have done as you suggested and it works! Thank you!

Can you explain why it is different to have concatenated the expression this way?

Comment: I already explained the reason of not using word boundary. Additionally you don't need to surround your regex with single quotes, just surround it with back tick as suggested since back tick is being used as regex delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Prepared Patterns](https://t-regx.com/docs/handling-user-input) which is designed **specifically** to handle unsafe characters. It doesn't only escape characters, but escapes whitespace if `x` flag is used, handles special `\Q\E` escapes, comments `#` (basically every possible scenario with PHP regexps).

```
$pattern = Pattern::prepare(["`\b", [$artist_name], "\b`"]);
```

It also automatically chooses delimiters for you